# In what way does Sharding allocate transactions for each shard? state? or node selection?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, sharding

In what way does **Sharding** allocate transactions for each shard?

I know that accounts are assigned to each shard based on prefix in the account's address and each shard processes the transactions related to that account.

---

**Example)**

shard1(0x00... ~ 0x01...), shard2(0x01... ~ 0x02...), ..., shard100

---

If not, I would appreciate it if you could let me know how ethereum **Sharding** is proposing this works.

Also, if you know how to allocate transactions in **Sharding** of other blockchain platforms, I would be grateful if you could let me know.

Answer (score 0):

However the people want to. Shards will essentially be their own chain, except the chain is built using the PoS consensus in the beacon chain. If a dApp is on a shard, people will have an account on that shard to interact with that dApp's contracts. People will likely have accounts on several different shards based on what dApps they use.